# Woocommerce Subscription - Changing Free Trial Text

Tags: string, woocommerce, subscription, subscriptions

Thank you for reading this post.  I have been trying to change the "Free Trial" text in Woocommerce Subscriptions.  I was able to find code to change "Sign Up Fee" but have not been able to find ability to change this other section.

```
    function change_subscription_product_string( $subscription_string, $product, $include ){
if( $include['sign_up_fee'] ){
    $subscription_string = str_replace('sign-up fee', '= total price. After intro period subscription will renew monthly.', $subscription_string);
}
return $subscription_string; } add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'change_subscription_product_string', 10, 3 );
```

The code I have currently created is : "$199.00 for 1 month with a 2-month **free trial** and a $398.00 = total price. After intro period subscription will renew monthly."

Need to change to "$199.00 for 1 month with a 2-month **minimum** and a $398.00 = total price. After intro period subscription will renew monthly.

Comment: Wanted to see if anyone may know of a secondary string that may be able to influence this section?

Answer (score 0):

I had success with this snippet:

```
function wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string( $pricestring ) {
    $newprice = str_replace( 'free trial', 'minimum', $pricestring );
    return $newprice;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscription_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
```

from Woo's official [woogist github gist account](https://gist.github.com/woogist/fb02f7b1752c2c53773d#file-functions-php) via [nicola.blog](https://nicola.blog/2015/08/06/how-to-change-the-price-string-in-woocommerce-subscriptions/)